# How to show related news with image in tx:news (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I am using tx news in the current version and try to display the related news with the preview image. 
The title of the news is shown with:

```
<n:link newsItem="{related}" settings="{settings}" title="{related.title}">
{related.title} 
</n:link>
```

Does anybody know how to display also the preview image of the related news?

```
{related.media}
```

does not work at all.

Many thanks in advance, urs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the original extension templates. Media items are included via Partial. You could just render one of those and pass the news item as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint of sven (many thanks!) – here is the answer:

To render date, title and image of all related news write into the template:

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.allRelatedSorted}" as="related">
<li>
<span class="news-related-news-date"><f:format.date format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}">{related.datetime}</f:format.date></span>
<n:link newsItem="{related}" settings="{settings}" title="{related.title}">
{related.title}
</n:link>
<f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaContainer" arguments="{media: related.falMedia, settings:settings}" />
<f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: related.media, settings:settings}" />
</li>
</f:for>
```